# EntityFramwork generating Interfaces for MEF

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, interface, mef, edmx

I am playing around building some buildingblocks based on database tables.

So I've created an UsersManager and a ValidationManager both based on the EDMX "templates".

I'd really like to loose couple those two components with MEF. But therefore i need to create Interfaces of the entityobjects exposed in the ValidationManager. 
Is there an easy way of creating those Interfaces, in that manner i can still use the EDMX generated classes?

Thanx, 
Paul

Answer (score 0):

Using an example of a database with a `Product` Table, is this what you're trying to achieve....

[image]

but still use generated entity classes (using either the standard EF generator or another POCO generator of some sort).

I'm not sure - as you mention MEF and I don't see it being directly related.

The generated entity classes are partial classes which will allow you to extend the generated class which in this case you want to extend to implement an interface.

Presuming the following interface is going to be used to introduce the layer of abstraction...

```
    public interface IEntity {
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    }
```

Create a new class file with and extended `Product` class...

```
    public partial class Product : IEntity {
        public bool IsDeleted {
            get {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            set {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }
```

You have now extended your generated entity `Product` with the partial class custom code - and you can use it as normal through EF.

Now instead of your `UserManager` and `ValidationManager` classes having a hard reference to `Product`, instead they'll only have  reference to `IEntity`.

If I didn't understand the question, please provide more details on exactly it is you want to do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i think i didnt made myself clear :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i think i didnt made myself clear :)
The ValidationManager is a Class which consumes 2 partial Classes Validation and ValidationCode, both tables in the database.

As same for the UserManager, which consists of 7 tables :)

In the ValidationManager the Partial Class "Validation" is generated. From this class i would like to have an Interface in a separated hard linked library in both ValidationManager as also in UserManager.. Does this make more sense?

Comment: Also, ive missed something .... the partial class is capable of being "interfaced".

So i refactored the Interfaces of Validation and ValidationAction, put the Interface in the class:  public partial class Validation : EntityObject, IValidation and moved them over to a separated Project.. now it functs :D